# Correct usage of "used to"

Tags: sentence-construction

Should I use 'used to' even when something just doesn't happen only today but will happen tomorrow?

Should I use 'used to' for this kind of sentence also.

> I normally leave at 5 pm from office, at that time it didn't **use to** be so dark but today I left at 7 pm and that is why it is dark.

Is this correct way of speaking?

Comment: It's [***used*** *to*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/is-it-used-to-or-use-to), not ***use*** *to*.

Comment: I am not speaker english but used to is when you are using for many time something like : "I used to  walk to my work  it's hard but I do not have money" sorry if my english is not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Your example sentence is confusing and hard to understand.

> I normally leave the office at 5pm   [notice the idiomatic way of saying this]
>
> At that time  [presumably 5pm]
>
> it didn't use to be so dark

This part is hard to follow.  I suppose it means "it used to be light". Which implies that it is now dark at 5pm.  But we know that the time when it gets dark follows the seasons and so this usage seems very odd.

> but today I left at 7pm and that is why it is dark.

This seems to be a non-sequitar. You are jumping from 5 to 7 and from light to dark. It seems very strange.

> It was completely dark when I left the office today. I normally leave at 5 pm. In summer it is still light, but In winter it is already dark at five.  Moreover, I stayed until 7 pm.

However if you mean it is sunny at 5 but dark at 7, then your sentence is wrong and you should be using a different tense.

> It was completely dark when I left the office today. I normally leave at in the light at 5pm, but today I didn't leave until 7.

You could say

> I'm late today (I left at 7 pm) and now it is dark but I normally leave at 5pm in the sun.

Comment: I mean I left late today at 7pm(sun was set at that time) this is not normal for me because I leave at 5 pm daily(sun used to be present at that time of the day).

Comment: You are now contradicting yourself. Either the sun *is* present at 5pm  or it *used to be present* at 5pm. If you say "it used to be present at 5pm" that means "today it isn't present at 5pm". However you actually need to rephrase.  Don't use "used to"; it is incorrect.

Comment: Then please tell me how to say this sentence?

Comment: I'm late today(left at 7 pm) and now it is dark but normally leave at 5pm in the presence of the sun

Answer (score 0):

Since you are referring to something routine, you can use the simple present tense:

> I normally leave at 5 pm from office, at that time it **isn't** so dark, but today I left at 7 pm and that is why it is dark.

Using "used to" would be appropriate if in the past, it was not dark at 5 pm, but now is.

Comment: 'It isn't' is not appropriate I think because that thing is not happening today.

Answer (score -1):

In this context, you are saying that it was previously light out when you left. This is perfectly acceptable in conversation. I would recommend using, "it wasn't" in more formal writing though.